# Убрать наложение диаграммы в Андроид - MPAndroidChart

Tags: android

Подключил диаграмму к приложению из библиотеки MPAndroidChart. Все работает, но есть наложение друг на друга. То есть если я построил одну диаграмму, задал новые параметры и создал вторую, то новая ляжет по верх старой. При вращении диаграммы это видно. Как устранить?

Comment: В вопросе слишком мало информации, приведите, пожалуйста, код, чтобы люди могли Вам помочь. Навскидку, дело может быть в том, что вы дважды добавляете `View` на экран.

Comment: Вы правы, добавил diagrammLayout.removeAllViews(); и все работает как надо. Добавьте ответ, отмечу его как правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, Вы дважды добавляете View на экран.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/135780)

Comment: @m9_psy Согласен, но посмотрите в комментарии к вопросу автора. Я запросил больше информации и высказал предположение, оказавшееся верным, которое автор и попросил вынести в ответ.